# Рассылка доходит не до всех пользователей в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот, рассылка

здравствуйте прошу помочь мне с такой вот проблемой. У меня есть телеграм бот в котором почти 1000 пользователей. В нем я сделал рассылку (код ниже) и эта рассылка доходит почему-то не до всех пользователей. User-id я беру из базы данных. Очень многим рассылка приходит, а кому-то вообще нет, сколько бы раз я не пробовал. Никаких ошибок бот не выдает и в конце, через минуты 3-4 присылает сообщение об успешной рассылке.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='sendall', is_chat_admin=True)
async def sendall(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == мой айди:
        text = message.text[9:]
        users = await sqlite_db.get_users()
        for row in users:
            try:
                await bot.send_message(row[0], text)
                await asyncio.sleep(.05)
            except:
                pass


        await bot.send_message(ADMINS_CHAT_ID, "Успешная рассылка")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты спрашивал всю 1000 пользователей, приходит им сообщение или нет?

Comment: Нет, у меня стоит отслеживание кол-ва человек которые сразу же после того как им приходит рассылка нажимают кнопку, а нажатие кнопки я отслеживаю и вижу, что очень многим все же рассылка приходит.

Comment: А те, кто заблокировал бота? А если проигнорили и ничего не нажали?

Comment: Вот получается нужно отследить кто заблокировал бота, скажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а в случае pass у меня может быть что на ошибке цикл останавливается и остальных пользователей из базы даже не трогает? Как мне вывести ошибку в консоль и продолжить цикл?

Comment: @RED123123 по-видимому это aiogram 2, можно отлавливать исключени BotBlocked https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/v2.25.1/utils/exceptions.html#aiogram.utils.exceptions.BotBlocked

Comment: @RED123123 нет, цикл не останавливается. При появлении исключения срабатывает блок except, но из-за того, что там pass ничего не происходит и цикл продолжается. Ну можно print вписать в except, вместо pass

Comment: То есть написать вместо pass print, но тогда продолжится ли цикл?

Comment: @RED123123 да, цикл будет продолжаться

Comment: Ок. Но у меня же стоит pass, значит тех, кто заблокировал бота pass пропускает, тогда почему тем, кто не блокировал бота, не приходит рассылка?

Comment: Может быть мне стоит вписать сейчас в exept: print(), сделать рассылку и посмотреть что выдаст консоль?

Comment: @RED123123 слово pass ничего не делает, его пишут, предполагая, что на его месте будет какой-то код. А сейчас, в таком виде, при появлении исключения ничего не происходит. Пишите там print, смотрите какие возникают ошибки

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, вот что в консоль написало: Forbidden: user is deactivated, Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user и так много раз. Но если пользователь просто заблокировал бота, по идее оно с помощью pass его пропускает и дальше всем остальным должно прислать. Тогда почему некоторым, кто не блокировал бота рассылка не приходит?

Comment: Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: @RED123123 ну так смотрите логи. Попробуйте отправить сообщение только тому, которому рассылка, якобы, не доходит и смотрите что в консоли

Comment: Я сейчас по tg id сделал рассылку конкретно тому человеку, которому не приходит рассылка и все пришло ему. В чем же проблема?

Comment: Я сделал вывод логов в файлик и вот что там выдало при рассылке, которую я только что сделал ...venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.UserDeactivated: Forbidden: user is deactivated
Эта ошибка была у меня и в консоли и я так понимаю, что после этой ошибки бот перестает идти по базе данных. Как с этой ошибкой справиться?

Comment: В таких случаях пишут что: Чтобы рассылка не умирала из-за одной ошибки, можно обернуть в try/except, но она у меня уже и так обернута в это.

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО! Я изменил в коде на вот такие строчки, сделал рассылку и оно мне выдало около 100 пользователей у которых было - Forbidden: user is deactivated и Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user. После этого я скопировал все tg id и удалил их вручную из базы данных, после этого все заработало! Всем спасибо кто уделил время.

```
    if message.from_user.id == МОЙ ТГ АЙДИ:
        text = message.text[9:]
        users = await sqlite_db.get_users()
        for row in users:
            try:
                await bot.send_message(row[0], text)
                await asyncio.sleep(.05)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Не удалось отправить сообщение пользователю {row}: {e}")

        await bot.send_message(ADMINS_CHAT_ID, "Успешная рассылка")
```

Comment: Круто, что ты разобрался! Но, по-хорошему, эти исключения нужно обрабатывать, а не просто выводить в консоль. Блокировку бота пользователем можно отслеживать, отлавливая апдэйт my_chat_member. user is deactivated же, насколько я понимаю, это удаленные аккаунты. А если завтра еще кто-нибудь заблокирует бота или удалит аккаунт? При таких исключениях, желательно, сразу бы вносить изменения в БД, а потом присылать какой-нибудь итог. Типа: Рассылка успешная. Забанили бота: 10, Удалили акк: 20

Comment: Очень хорошая идея, спасибо! А у вас есть предположения как можно это сделать? Попробую сейчас тоже подумать как это реализовать.